# The Pearson correlation coefficient is lower for the samples than for the population. Why?

Tags: statistics, correlation

A population is assumed to be divided into samples such that the samples are disjoint (the intercept is zero) and the union of the samples is the population. Why can the Pearson correlation coefficient for each sample all be smaller in numerical value than the population correlation coefficient?

Note. All coefficients are positive

Example
The population has two variables and we want to know what correlation the two variables have.

u--population

a_1--sample 1

a_2--sample 2

a_2--sample 3

Both the sample and the population have the two variables to which we have the correlation

The intercept between the 3 samples is zero and the union is µ.

Correlation of a_1=0.23

Correlation of a_2=0.26

Correlation of a_3=0.19

Correlation of µ= 0.28

Why can the population correlation be numerically greater than the samples correlation?

I can't find any logic in this.

A sample should at least be larger numerically, for example:

Correlation of a_1=0.23

**Correlation of a_2=0.30**

Correlation of a_3=0.19

Correlation of u= 0.28

Comment: When you say "less", do you mean "closer to 0" or "closer to -1"?

Comment: Smells like Simpson's paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The correlation with what? (And you presumably mean the intersection rather than intercept is zero)

Comment: I have edited the question to explain it better, sorry

Comment: One can easily make an example where the correlations of three separate populations are **zero** but when you put them all together you have a strong correlation. What is the source of this question?

Comment: Thank you very much David K, I have found an example. I had no idea.

Comment: @Arthur - once you have seen Simpson's paradox, it is obvious you can create examples where the overall population pairs have a correlation arbitrarily close to any desired number in $[-1,1]$ while the parts all have correlations arbitrarily close to any other desired number in $[-1,1]$